# I need to push data to a table post uploading file. Is there any way of doing it without triggers

Tags: php

I am uploading data into temp table after uploading. I need to performs joins and select few columns and push those data to another table in php . Is there any way of doing it without using triggers

Comment: `INSERT INTO table .... SELECT ....` read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: For what reason do you want to avoid triggers? What database are you using? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a trigger to react to an insertion in a database, you pretty much need to do it by polling that table to see if there is new insertions at a given time interval. You will need a flag in that polled table to know if a row has already been processed in a previous run to prevent reacting multiple times for a single insert.

One way of doing this could be with a CRON job ran at every minutes that execute a php script that simply "select all rows of your table where the "isProcessed" flag is false". Of course the default value for the "isProcessed" column must be false.

Then for each row obtained with the previous DB query, you do what you want to do, i.e. "performs joins and select few columns and push those data to another table in php" to quote yourself.

Then update the same rows in your original "temp" table so that their "isProcessed" is now at true.

I guess you have a good reason not to use database triggers , because triggers are there to do exactly what you want to do in the simplest way that it can be done.

Comment: Hi ,  Thank you for your suggestion I am new to php . could you able to explain with example script , that would be helpful for me .